# Understanding SQL EXPLAIN on a JOIN query

Tags: sql, postgresql, explain

I'm struggling to make sense of postgres EXPLAIN to figure out why my query is slow. Can someone help? This is my query, it's a pretty simple join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT graph_concepts.* 
FROM graph_concepts 
INNER JOIN graph_family_links 
        ON graph_concepts.id = graph_family_links.descendent_concept_id 
WHERE graph_family_links.ancestor_concept_id = 1016 
AND graph_family_links.generation = 1 
AND graph_concepts.state != 2
```

It's starting from a concept and it's getting a bunch of related concepts through the links table.

Notably, I have an index on graph_family_links.descendent_concept_id, yet this query takes about 3 seconds to return a result. This is way too long for my purposes.

This is the SQL explain:

```
 Unique  (cost=46347.01..46846.16 rows=4485 width=108) (actual time=27.406..33.667 rows=13 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=13068 read=5
   I/O Timings: read=0.074
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=46347.01..46825.98 rows=4485 width=108) (actual time=27.404..33.656 rows=13 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 1
         Workers Launched: 1
         Buffers: shared hit=13068 read=5
         I/O Timings: read=0.074
         ->  Sort  (cost=45347.01..45348.32 rows=2638 width=108) (actual time=23.618..23.621 rows=6 loops=2)
               Sort Key: graph_concepts.id, graph_concepts.definition, graph_concepts.checkvist_task_id, graph_concepts.primary_question_id, graph_concepts.created_at, graph_concepts.updated_at, graph_concepts.tsn, graph_concepts.state, graph_concepts.search_phrases
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Buffers: shared hit=13068 read=5
               I/O Timings: read=0.074
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=301.97..45317.02 rows=2638 width=108) (actual time=8.890..23.557 rows=6 loops=2)
                     Buffers: shared hit=13039 read=5
                     I/O Timings: read=0.074
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on graph_family_links  (cost=301.88..39380.60 rows=2640 width=4) (actual time=8.766..23.293 rows=6 loops=2)
                           Recheck Cond: (ancestor_concept_id = 1016)
                           Filter: (generation = 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 18850
                           Heap Blocks: exact=2558
                           Buffers: shared hit=12985
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_graph_family_links_on_ancestor_concept_id  (cost=0.00..301.66 rows=38382 width=0) (actual time=4.744..4.744 rows=47346 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (ancestor_concept_id = 1016)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=67
                     ->  Index Scan using graph_concepts_pkey on graph_concepts  (cost=0.08..2.25 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=13)
                           Index Cond: (id = graph_family_links.descendent_concept_id)
                           Filter: (state <> 2)
                           Buffers: shared hit=54 read=5
                           I/O Timings: read=0.074
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=19
 Planning Time: 0.306 ms
 Execution Time: 33.747 ms
(35 rows)
```

I'm doing lots of googling to help me figure out how to read this EXPLAIN and I'm struggling. Can someone help translate this into plain english for me?

---

Answering myself (for the benefit of future people):

My question was primarily how to understand EXPLAIN. Many people below contributed to my understanding but no one really gave me the beginner unpacking I was looking for. I want to teach myself to fish rather than simply having other people read this and give me advice on solving this specific issue, although I do greatly appreciate the specific suggestions!

For others trying to understand EXPLAIN, this is the important context you need to know, which was holding me back:

- "Cost" is some arbitrary unit of how expense each step of the process is, you can think of it almost like a stopwatch.
- Look near the end of your EXPLAIN until you find: `cost=0.00..` This is the very start of your query execution. In my case, `cost=0.00..301.66` is the first step and `cost=0.08..2.25` runs in parallel (from step 0.08 to step 2.25, just a small fraction of the 0 to 300).
- Find the step with the biggest "span" of cost. In my case, `cost=301.88..39380.60`. Although I was confused because I also have a `cost=301.97..45317.02`. I think those are, again, both happening in parallel so I'm not sure which one is contributing more.

Comment: Please post complete query and results form EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS). Also post table definition (DDL script).

Comment: Your performance enemy is probably the horrible combination of `select distinct` together with with `select *`.  Choose the columns you actually need instead, don't use *, then it might perform better. **OR**, you need to join to a subquery instead of the table - with that subquery reducing the columns/rows as needed.

Comment: some useful link: https://www.pgmustard.com/  https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/how-to-interpret-postgresql-explain-analyze-output/

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan

Comment: Your new plan shows it took only .033 seconds.  Maybe it is faster now because all the data is in memory, or maybe you misread the original timing.

Comment: Were you able to optimize the query ? It could be interesting to see how did you resolve that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Explain read from bottom to up, generally.
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

> This command displays the execution plan that the PostgreSQL planner
> generates for the supplied statement. The execution plan shows how the
> table(s) referenced by the statement will be scanned — by plain
> sequential scan, index scan, etc. — and if multiple tables are
> referenced, what join algorithms will be used to bring together the
> required rows from each input table.

Since you only do `explain your select command` meaning the output is the system planner generate a execute  plan for this select query. But if you do explain analyze then it will plan and execute the query.

- First there is two table there. For each table use some ways to found out which rows meet the where criteria.  **index scan** (one of the way to find out where is the row) found out in table graph_concepts  which row meet the condition: graph_concepts.state != 2.
  Also in the mean time(Parallel) use  **Bitmap Heap Scan** to found out in table
  graph_family_links which row meet the criteria: graph_family_links.ancestor_concept_id = 1016
- After that then do join operation. In this case, it's Nested Loop.
- After join then do Sort. Why we need to sort operation? Because you specified: `SELECT DISTINCT` : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html
  -After sort then since you specified key word DISTINCT then eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: I updated my original question with the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE, in case that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I read and re-read everyone's answers but yours was the most foundational explanation that helped me to begin to untangle how to even make sense of the EXPLAIN output. I appreciate your help!

There is one key thing about my EXPLAIN which I still can't figure out. My JOIN operation is an expensive Nested Loop `cost=301.97..45317.02`. But immediately after this is a Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on graph_family_links with almost the same cost `(cost=301.88..39380.60)`.

I assume these are happening in parallel? Which is my real culprit, then?

Comment: @KeithSchacht I am not sure. But I found these two links maybe will be helpful for you to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211067/how-to-understand-the-nested-loop-in-postgresql-explain  https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/12553.1135634231%40sss.pgh.pa.us#bf329c95dc1ad2c6e3eb91e71c600db8

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    graph_concepts.* 
FROM
    graph_concepts
    INNER JOIN graph_family_links ON graph_concepts.id = graph_family_links.descendent_concept_id 
WHERE
    graph_family_links.ancestor_concept_id = 1016 
    AND graph_family_links.generation = 1 
    AND graph_concepts.state != 2

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=46347.01..46846.16 rows=4485 width=108)
   ## (Merge records DISTINCT)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=46347.01..46825.98 rows=4485 width=108)
         Workers Planned: 1
                 
        ## (Sort table graph_concepts.* )
         ->  Sort  (cost=45347.01..45348.32 rows=2638 width=108)
               Sort Key: graph_concepts.id, graph_concepts.definition, graph_concepts.checkvist_task_id, graph_concepts.primary_question_id, graph_concepts.created_at, graph_concepts.updated_at, graph_concepts.tsn, graph_concepts.state, graph_concepts.search_phrases
                             
                             
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=301.97..45317.02 rows=2638 width=108)
                     ## WHERE graph_family_links.ancestor_concept_id = 1016     (Use Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan table and filter record)
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on graph_family_links  (cost=301.88..39380.60 rows=2640 width=4)
                           Recheck Cond: (ancestor_concept_id = 1016)
                           Filter: (generation = 1)
                                                     
                            ## AND graph_family_links.generation = 1 (Use Bitmap Index Scan table and filter record)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_graph_family_links_on_ancestor_concept_id  (cost=0.00..301.66 rows=38382 width=0)
                                 Index Cond: (ancestor_concept_id = 1016)
                     
                                         
                                ## AND graph_concepts.state != 2 (Use Index Scan table and filter record)
                                ->  Index Scan using graph_concepts_pkey on graph_concepts  (cost=0.08..2.25 rows=1 width=108)
                                Index Cond: (id = graph_family_links.descendent_concept_id)
                                Filter: (state <> 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please refer to the below sql script.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT graph_concepts.* 
FROM graph_concepts
    INNER JOIN (select descendent_concept_id from graph_family_links where ancestor_concept_id = 1016 and generation = 1) A ON graph_concepts.id = A.descendent_concept_id 
WHERE graph_concepts.state != 2
```

Comment: Good translation, but your rewrite of the query is not an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

People have given you general links and advice on understanding plans.  To focus on one relevant part of the plan, it expects to find 38382 rows satisfying `ancestor_concept_id = 1016`, but then well over 90% of them are expected to fail the `generation = 1` filter.  But that is expensive as it was to jump to some random table page to fetch the "generation" value to apply the filter.

If you had a combined index on `(ancestor_concept_id, generation)` it could apply both restrictions efficiently simultaneously.  Alternatively, of you had separate single column indexes on those columns, it could combine then with a BitmapAnd operation.  That would be more efficient than what you are currently doing to but less efficient than the combined index.

Comment: I really appreciate this suggestion! I added a generation index and it's helping quite a bit and there are many cases where I will filter on `generation`. How do I decide whether I should also add a (ancestor_concept_id, generation) index. How do I determine how much more it might help and what the "cost" to this extra index would be? And is that cost simply database storage space or is it also a write cost?

Comment: Since you already have an index on ancestor_concept_id, replacing it with one on `(ancestor_concept_id,generation)` should have almost no extra cost.